# Is it on topic to ask about Uber app?

Tags: support, scope

I am a heavy Uber customer, and I am facing a problem in changing the phone number in the app when visiting new countries.

Is it on topic to ask here about it or should I ask in webapps.se?

Comment: Does Uber have any support/customer service ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Yes.. It seems it's only possible through their customer service.. Opening a ticket and so on.. I want a practical solution to do that once I reach a country and get a sim..

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it would be off topic at _web apps_ because it's a mobile app, not web apps. Not sure about here, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's on-topic here to ask technical questions about websites/apps that are totally travel related. I've answered questions on how to deal with the web-interfaces of various travel-related entities. No talk of off-topic, and plenty of upvotes for [the questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77313/41775). I don't see why it should be different just because it's an app.

If you're asking about a web interface, it might be on-topic at Web Apps SE, but I'm not sure. If you're talking about a mobile app, then it's off-topic for Web Apps SE. As for Android SE, Ask Different and Windows Phone SE, I'm not sure, but my first search shows me that a question [got closed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114027/131868) at Android SE. You can try searching yourself, to see how the various sites like such questions.